# virtualenv not active when run from a shell script

Tags: python, unix

When I run `source venv/bin/activate` in command line , it activates the virtualenv. However when run this via a shell script `./run.sh` , I don't see the virtualenv being activated. Similar scripts used to work for me in the past , however I am not sure what I am missing now. I am running this is on a mac.

```
#! /bin/bash
source venv/bin/activate
```

`(venv) 8c859072374671e:my-project tee78$`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "seeing". You won't see anything that happens in a shell script, surely; any changes to the environment will only happen in the subshell that script is running in, and won't persist beyond its run.

Comment: This is not really python related.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I used to see (venv) when I ran the shell script in the past.  I used to type deactivate to get out of the venv. Now I am not seeing that which makes me believe that venv is not active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are running `source` inside a script. It is running in a new environment. It won't get reflected in the parent shell.

```
$ cat run.sh
#! /bin/bash
source venv/bin/activate
```

It you need that to happen do, `source` your script,

```
source run.sh
```

Also, you won't need the `shebang` line :)

Comment: Thank you! using source helped me :)

Comment: May the `source` be with you :)